# SQL server environment

Tags: sql-server

I'm considering a bit of changes in current sales environment. And trying to check all cons and pros.
Current situation.
SQL server (quite decent HP server - server1) + backup server (smaller Dell server - server2).
all sql files and sql server itself are on the server1. If something goes wrong with server1 I will have to manually move to server2.
Connecting to the sql server: 1 HQ (where server located) + 4 sites through VPN.

Now I'm considering 2 scenarios:

1. Buy some storage system + update existing servers (add ram, upgrade processors) and go for VMWare ESXI.
2. Rent a server at a datacenter + rent virtual server in case real server goes down. Also rent some space at data storage to keep SQL files there.

Have anyone considered these things and maybe found some good pros/cons list? ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's always up to you - these variants will just have different price and performance, and I can't say which one is better based on provided information.

For #2 you might have "disabled" virtual server (cloud things) - so that you are not paying for it when you don't need it. You may combine this option with your first variant.

Answer (score 1):

What are your requirements?

- Are you looking for automatic failover to the backup server or is the manual process okay?
- How much storage is required?
- What is the concurrent usage?
- If HQ could not connect to the SQL Server because the remote link is down, how does that
  affect your productivity?

How old are your current servers and what is their warranty status? Are they within consideration to migrate to ESX servers?

Answer (score 0):

- Manual is ok also if getting automatic will be costly
- Current database is about 17GB (both data file and transaction file)
- In current situation if HQ has problems with connection, then other sites are also down. One of the pros of using server in Datacenter is that usually providers react more quickly to the problems in datacenter then to the problems with separate customer :)

Main server is almost 3 years old with standard HP warranty.